# I'm getting imaginary eigenvalues of $X^2-P^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, eigenvalue

This is hermitian but I'm getting imaginary eigenvalues. Start with the commutator:

$$[X^2-P^2,X+P]$$

$$=[X^2,P]-[P^2,X]$$

$$=X[X,P]+[X,P]X-(P[P,X]+[P,X]P)$$

$$=2i(X+P)$$

Now consider the ket $|E\rangle$ such that $(X^2-P^2)|E\rangle=E|E\rangle$

$$(X^2-P^2)(X+P)|E\rangle$$
$$=(X+P)(X^2-P^2)|E\rangle+[X^2-P^2, X+P] |E\rangle$$

$$=E(X+P) |E\rangle + 2i (X+P)|E\rangle$$

The above proves that the ket $(X+P)|E\rangle$ has eigenvalue $E+2i$, which is imaginary. How can it be?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138261/discussion-on-question-by-ryder-rude-im-getting-imaginary-eigenvalues-of-x2-p).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is formulated in a such vague manner that it is not possible to properly answer.

*This is a mathematical issue and to answer it is necessary to fix all mathematical hypotheses.*

First of all: What is the domain of $P^2-X^2$?

A standard domain is the space of Schwartz functions. On that dense domain the operator is *symmetric* and commutes with the standard complex conjugation. As a consequence, it admits selfadjoint extensions, but this fact it is quite irrelevant here. I do not expect that there is a unique selfadjoint extension (I think that the problem has been completely analyzed in the literature, but I cannot check it now).
However, all manipulations with commutators which appear in the post are valid in the Schwartz space, since it is invariant under $P$ and $X$  and I assume that $|E\rangle$ is an eigenvector in that domain. The existence of $|E\rangle$ can be checked directly by solving the corresponding differential equation (actually I do *not* expect that such a vector exists).

Since symmetric operators have real point spectrum, the conclusion in the post  is untenable and the only possibility is that $(X+P)|E\rangle =0$.

I repeat, with the given domain, everything can be directly checked from scratch and I think that simply the initial $|E\rangle$ does not exist in the Schwartz space.

More exotic choices of the domain or intepretations of $|E\rangle$ (e.g. a Schwartz distribution) should be analyzed case by case with **precise** definitions and without them it is impossible to answer.

Comment: I just assumed that $|E\rangle$ was a square integrable function because I thought spectral theorem applied here. Is the space of Schwartz functions, like, a superset of $L^2$ functions? We're only allowed $L^2$ and *not* Schwartz functions in QM, right?

Comment: Yes, if you assume they are not Schwartz, then you should deal with commutators properly. For example does $|E\rangle$ belong to the domain if $P+X$? If yes, does $(P+X)|E\rangle$  belong to the domain of $P^2-X^2$?

Comment: Notice also that the standard ccr of X and P are guaranteed on the Schwartz space, on larger domains you should also prove the validity of the ccr.

Comment: @RyderRude Schwartz functions form a dense subspace in $L^2$.

Comment: Yes, the Schwartz space is a dense *sub*space of $L^2(R)$

Comment: I found [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0703234%23:~:text%3DThe%2520inverted%2520harmonic%2520oscillator%2520is,associated%2520with%2520the%2520inverted%2520oscillator.&ved=2ahUKEwjc8M3asKf5AhVqDbcAHSSBD3EQFnoECAQQBg&usg=AOvVaw2CvQkkibIsSgayIjYA7ijR) short paper saying that the eigenvectors of this inverted oscillator are indeed not square integrable. So, this is just a mathematical problem, right? We can't call it physics if there's no probabilistic interpretation. But the paper also talks about some physical applications.

Comment: They also derived a discrete spectrum of this, which is normalizable

Comment: The wavefunctions they obtained also have a $e^{-\omega t}$ factor in the evolution, which means it is non-unitary. So I don't think this mathematical problem can be interpreted as a quantum mechanics.

Comment: The notions of eigenvalue and eigenvector the paper adopts are not the standard ones. For instance, the eigenvalues depend on time but the Hamiltonian does not. Also it does seem to me that the eigenvectors satisfy the eigenvector equation. Everything is misunderstood.

Comment: However it does not make sense to continue this discussion.